# RewriteRule using HTTP_HOST and a different port

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to use the HTTP_HOST header in a RewriteRule but change the port
I cannot use SERVER_NAME as it will be different from the host header (which is what I need)

Is there a way to trim the :port off of the HTTP_HOST variable for mod_rewrite?

Comment: Do you mean you are running Apache on a different port?

Comment: %{SERVER_PORT} contains the port of the server. Could you edit your question to be more descriptive?

Comment: It needs to use the http_host to redirect to the proper external server.  this virtualsite is not on port 80

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can trim the port off of the host header. Just match against `%{HTTP_HOST}` and use a `%1` backreference. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1:12345/ [R,L]
```

---

Just keep in mind that the `%1` backreference can only be used in the first parameter of a `RewriteCond`, and not in a match:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteCond %1 ^the.hostname.com$ [NC]
```

is ok

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^%1
```

is NOT ok